# overridePendingTransition duration is ignored

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions, overridependingtransition

I'm using overridePendingTransition to set my own activity transition. Everything works fine except that I cannot change to duration of the animation, it is ignored.

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:zAdjustment="top"/>

</set>
```

**stay.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:zAdjustment="top"/>
```

The duration is set to 2000 ms but the animation is still just a fraction of a second long. Even changing it to an extreme value like 10000 does nothing.

If I change the animations in Developer options in settings, the animation duration corresponds to the given settings.

Java code for reference:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void games(View view){

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GamesActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.stay);


}
```

Anyone that has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since you asked this but I just experienced this.

Try doing a clean build. That fixed it for me. Looks like Instant Run causes the animations to not be updated on every run.